# Solution to Heat-Like Equation with Diverging Initial Condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve the equation
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}F(x; \alpha) = \lambda \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}F(x; \alpha) \qquad (1)$$
with the condition $F(x; \alpha = 0) = \exp(\ln 2 \, e^{x})$. Since (1) is the diffusion equation, it seems that one can use the point source solution
$$G(x; \alpha) = \frac{1}{(4 \pi \lambda \alpha)^{1/2}} \exp\left( - \frac{x^2}{4 \lambda \alpha}\right), \qquad (2)$$
which satisfies
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}G(x; \alpha) = \lambda \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}G(x; \alpha)\, ; \qquad G(x; \alpha=0) = \delta (x),$$
to write the general solution
\begin{align}
F(x; \alpha) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dx' \, F(x'; 0) G(x-x'; \alpha). \qquad (3)
\end{align}
However with $F(x;\alpha) = \exp(\ln 2 e^{x})$ and $G(x; \alpha)$ given in (2), the integrand of (3) diverges at $x \to \infty$. I'm guessing I'm violating some boundary condition assumption for (3) by using an initial condition that diverges at infinity, but I'm also not sure how else to construct a general solution to (1).

Is it possible to solve (1) with the initial condition $F(x;\alpha) = \exp(\ln 2 e^{x})$?